# Create select box dynamically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

i am creating a dynamic dropdowns based on a scenario i need to. i am wondering how it possible to keep the states of those added drop downs dynamically when a page is loading after submit button is clicked.

i am able to stote a variable in jquery and check whether form is submitted or not  and if submitted to load back the previously dynamically added dropdowns (html select box) but even though i load them back still i have a problem of getting the previously selected values of those dynamic dropdowns.

I have created a fiddler. http://jsfiddle.net/jBJSw/8/

My form

```
<form>
    <div id="TextBoxesGroup">
        <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
            <label>Textbox #1 :</label>
            <input type="text" id="textbox1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Add Button" id="addButton">
    <input type="submit" value="submit Button" id="subButton">
</form>
```

Script

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

      var counter = 2;

      $("#addButton").click(function () {

          if (counter > 10) {
              alert("Only 10 allow");
              return false;
          }

          var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
          newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Select #' + counter + ' : </label>' +
              '<select id="select' + counter + '" ><option value="' + "val" + ' ">"' + "desc2" + '"</option><option value="' + "val2" + ' ">"' + "desc" + '"</option><option value="' + "val3" + ' ">"' + "desc3" + '"</option>');

          newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
          counter++;
      });
  });
```

Appreciate if any help on finding a way to get the previously selected values after form submission. (this is needed because when a form is submitted with errors, these selected values should be same but now it refreshes and comes to default. also in a view scenario also this should be preloaded)

Comment: @DrixsonOseña cant we do it without ajax ? there is a limitation of using ajax in my case but if there is no way of going with jqyery or javascript then its fine with ajax

Comment: okay, let me provide you a solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for getting late have trouble in my work. Here's a possible solution for your problem.

DOM:

```
<form id="myform" method="post"> <!--adding id attribute-->
    <div id="TextBoxesGroup">
        <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
            <label>Textbox #1 :</label>
            <input type="text" id="textbox1">
        </div>

        <!--check if POST is established-->
        <?php if($_POST): ?>
            <?php if(count($_POST['mySelect']) < 0 ): ?>

            <?php

               //Recreate your select DOM
               $arr = $_POST['mySelect'];
               foreach($arr as $ind => $val){

                  echo '<select>';
                  echo '<option val="val" ' . ($val == "val" ? "selected" : "") . '>desc2</option>';
                  echo '<option val="val2" ' . ($val == "val2" ? "selected" : "") . '>desc</option>';
                  echo '<option val="val3" ' . ($val == "val3" ? "selected" : "") . '>desc3</option>';
                  echo '</select>';
               }

            ?>                


            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Add Button" id="addButton">
    <input type="submit" value="submit Button" id="subButton">
</form>
```

SCRIPT:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

      var counter = 2;

      $("#addButton").click(function () {

          if (counter > 10) {
              alert("Only 10 allow");
              return false;
          }

          var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
          newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Select #' + counter + ' : </label>' +
              '<select id="select' + counter + '" ><option value="' + "val" + ' ">"' + "desc2" + '"</option><option value="' + "val2" + ' ">"' + "desc" + '"</option><option value="' + "val3" + ' ">"' + "desc3" + '"</option>');

          newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
          counter++;
      });

     //adding hidden inputs
     $('#myFORM').on('submit', function(){

      $('#myFORM select').each(function(){
         slct = $('<input type="hidden" name="mySelect[]" value="' +  $(this).val() +'">');
         $('#myFORM').append(slct);
      });

  });
  });
```

Comment: let me know if there's need to adjust.. have work to do.. -.- user always complain

Comment: sorry abt the late, it doesnt work and i dont get submitted dropdowns relaoded. but i can get an idea of how to do now.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to send back the selected value to the page from server side in the querystring or post header. then select the option accordingly in jquery on the base of the the value sent back.

Comment: OP also need to recreate the DOM again.. like how many select tag.

Comment: @DrixsonOseña yes true, the issue here is i am able to get the no of added dynamic dropdowns but hard to assign the previously selected value to those again.

Comment: @Rab Nawaz yes i agree with you, but the thing is even if i sent the values to serevr and get back still after that happens only DOM is loaded and after dom is loaded only i am  creating dynamic drop downs again with jqeury

Comment: @mazraara, i can provide you a solution but it's not the best

Comment: @DrixsonOseña how will you handle it ? can you show with a fiddler pls

Comment: @ShareekAhamed, mix PHP/jquery. if OP doesn't want to use ajax

Comment: @DrixsonOseña i appreciate your example if you can provide it.  its going to be a my day saver.